# Excel Workbook overloading with memory when closing

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that is about 8mb with about 20 different API calls (via formula in cells) using a 3rd party service.  Everytime I try to close the workbook, excel goes Not Responding and the app comes to halt. The memory shoots up to like 2000-3000MB and sometimes it closes and other times I get a memory crash.

I do have a lot of vba code but nothing is running when I try to exit without saving.  As far I know the object memory goes null after a subroutine runs so I dont know where the memory leak is coming from.

Any ideas?

Comment: Having the code, formulas, and rough number of formulas would be helpful.

Comment: try to see if all updating finished before closing, there might be still something running in the background e.g data refresh etc.

Comment: Are the API calls via VBA using UDF's?  Seems like Excel wants to recalculate your workbook prior to closing.  You could try caching the API responses after the first call in a any Excel session, unless the return values are particularly time-sensitive

Comment: how would I cache data from a 3rd party add-in?

Answer (score 3):

I would start by turning off `CalculateBeforeSave` when you close the workbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.CalculateBeforeSave = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I had something similar with application.calculation  =xlManual.  Memory still shoots up to 3000mb when I try to close

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, if I open a blank workbook first and then open the big file ( FileX.xlsm) mentioned above when I close FileX, it has no memory leak.  But if I open FileX first and then try to close the memory shoots up to 3000-4000mb and my computer crashes.

Im wondering if the 3rd party add-in doesnt configure properly when FileX is opened from the start. Maybe by opening a blank file first the 3rd party add-in configures properly and prevents memory leaks when closing other big files.